# I'm using Datalogics APDFL SDK. how to print only the pdf pages containing a certain word?

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-pdf-library

I have imported Datalogics  maven sample source project in eclipse but don't know how to find the word and add them to print range and print specific pages that contain certain word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you contacted my company's Support department (tech_support@datalogics.com) already?  If not, you should do so to get more direct expert assistance.

The Java sample [ListWords](https://github.com/datalogics/adobe-pdf-library-samples/blob/master/Java/Sample_Source/Text/ListWords/src/com/datalogics/PDFL/Samples/ListWords.java) illustrates how to find the words on a page, iterate through that list of words, and retrieve the text.  The [PrintPDF](https://github.com/datalogics/adobe-pdf-library-samples/blob/master/Java/Sample_Source/Printing/PrintPDF/src/com/datalogics/PDFL/Samples/PrintPDF.java) sample illustrates how to specify a range of pages to print and how to print a document.  Examining these two samples would be helpful to see how you could selectively choose pages to print based on trigger words you find on those pages.